# What's it called when a date has the same 'day-number' as 'month-number'?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, numbers, dates

For example, my birthday is 9/9. My brothers' birthday is 12/12. Tomorrow will be 3/3. Is there a word that describes when it is the same date as the number we use to represent the month?

Please note that "palindrome" dates usually include the year, so while these numbers are kind of palindromes, I don't think that's the correct word to be applied.

Comment: Palindrome also wouldn't work because 12/21 would be the palindrome in December. An article about your case is here, with a source about as good as you're going to get: https://www.wellandgood.com/tiktok-trends-vsp-vision-pure/.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a clever term - one site calls them [repeating dates](https://www.timeanddate.com/date/special-dates.html), and more generally along with palindromic dates, incrementing/sequential dates, and others they can be called [fun dates](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/science-nature/last-sequential-date-century-121314-fun-math-lovers-180953413/).

Comment: They have the property of being the same on both sides of the Atlantic.

Answer (score 3):

Is **Bonza Bottler Day** the “word” you’re looking for? My 2nd grade teacher introduced me to this celebration and it has stuck with me for over two decades now.

According to the [Bonza Bottler Day website](https://www.bonzabottlerday.com/):

> Bonza Bottler Day is celebrated once a month when the number of the month coincides with the number of the day (Jan. 1, Feb. 2, March 3, etc.). When the number of the year also coincides with the number of the day and month (August 8, 2008), there is reason to have a bigger celebration (more food, more friends and more decorations). We call this a Bodacious Bonza Bottler Day. Bodacious means “extraordinary, impressively great in size, or enormous.” A baby born on a Bonza Bottler Day is known as a Bonza Bottler Baby which makes those birthday celebrations doubly special.

For an example in use, see [Merry Kids: Fun Ways to Celebrate Bonza Bottler Day](https://www.firstschool.net/blog/merry-kids-fun-ways-to-celebrate-bonza-bottler-day).

Comment: Hello, Jordan Can you add an independent reference endorsing this expression, and how common it is on the internet? Really niche usages (which this doesn't appear to be) are off-topic on ELU.

Comment: _Bonza Bottler Day_ is not the term for the phenomenon. This is the name of a specific celebration/event _when_ the numbers of the day and the month coincide.